# ClassLoader getDeclaredField instance error

Tags: java, classloader, instance, getmethod

Why when i try to invoke the method i get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

My code:

```
Class<?> tWCCamRes = tCLSLoader.loadClass("com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamResolution");
Field tVGA = tWCCamRes.getDeclaredField("VGA");

Method tMeth = tVGA.getDeclaringClass().getDeclaredMethod("getSize");
tMeth.invoke(tVGA, (Object[]) null); // Error
```

In theory I pass the object instance but it failed.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: No need to put the language in the title. The Java tag is sufficient.

Comment: I didn't know, i'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the method `getSize()`, using reflection, on an object of type `Field` (`tVGA`), instead of calling it on the *value* of this field, which is of type `WebcamResolution`.

Assuming that you really need to do this via reflection, the code should be:

```
Class<?> tWCCamRes = tCLSLoader.loadClass("com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamResolution");
Field tVGA = tWCCamRes.getDeclaredField("VGA");
Object vgaFieldValue = tVGA.get(null); // it's a static field, so the argument of get() can be null.

Method tMeth = tVGA.getDeclaringClass().getDeclaredMethod("getSize");
tMeth.invoke(vgaFieldValue);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly but can you explain me why "tVGA.get(null);" ? I'm new in classloader issue, sorry.

Comment: `field.get(Object o)` returns the value of the field for the object `o`. But here, the field is a static field. So it doesn't have any object to find the value of the field in. The field value is in the class itself. So the `o` argument is ignored. It's explained in the javadoc of `Field.get()`.

Comment: It's like you get the instance of class with "tVGA.get(null)" ? It's right ? This happens in all cases when you need to get the instance of the class?

Comment: Let's take a simpler example. You have an `Employee` class with a field `name`. You have two instances of Employee: `john` and `mary`. You want to get the name of mary using reflection. So you get the field "name" from the class `Employee`. And then you ask this field to tell what its value is in the object `mary`. That will return "Mary". Here, the field is a static field. Its value is in the class itself, not in an instance of the class. So you don't need to pass any instance to the `get()` method. `tVGA.get(null)` is the equivalent, without reflection, of `WebcamResolution.VGA`.

Comment: Now I understand. A very clear explanation! Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

You invoke the `getSize` method on the field `tVGA`, but the method is declared on com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamResolution.

If you want to invoke an instance method you have to pass the instance as the inovke method's first argument.

If the method doesn't take an argument like `com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamResolution.getSize()`
Just invoke it this way:

```
tMeth.invoke(webcamResolutionObj);
```

But why don't you just use the WebcamResolution enum.

```
 String enumName = "VGA";
 WebcamResolution wcResolution = WebcamResolution.valueOf(enumName);
 Dimension size = wcResolution.getSize();
```

Comment: Do you mean this: tMeth.invoke(tWCCamRes); ? It failed

Comment: I can't use directly "WebcamResolution" class, because i'm writting an client / server and i dont want include all libraries in client side app for not increase the size, so the client side application will download and use the libraries when it need. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: No tWCCamRes is the class object. You need an instance of that class to invoke the instance method, but like I answered.. why don't use the enum valueOf Method?

Comment: I took a look at the library. It is only 382k. You must have very strict memory requirements if you can not add this library to the client application.

Comment: There are 5 libraries more:                                    bridj-0.6.3-20130316.190111-13.jar
dx-1.7.jar
logback-core-1.0.13.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
slf4j-nop-1.7.5.jar